# How to integrate missing packages in COCOS2d Android 1

Tags: cocos2d-android

I was using COCOS2d android in my project and now i need to replace COCOS2d-android with The latest cocos2d. When i replace this jar it shows some package cannot be resolved errors in the below packages

import org.cocos2d.protocols.CCTouchDelegateProtocol;
import org.cocos2d.sound.SoundEngine;

Is their any latest COCOS2d android jar available with these files or is there any way to integreate these packages.

A question could arise why would i want to do this?? 
[How can i override ccTouchbegan in cocos2d-android( removal of overlaying sprites)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305027/how-can-i-override-cctouchbegan-in-cocos2d-android-removal-of-overlaying-sprite)